# SQL, dropping duplicates but keeping first row to mimic "greatest n per group" functionality

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm curious about what the best approach for this might be.

Currently, I have a dummy table that stores each time a person clocked in to work. It repeats a lot of info about that employee in each row, e.g. their name, their employee id, position, etc. The main thing different, of course, is the time stamp.

If I want the latest date each employee clocked in, I'm wondering how I would do it via a drop duplicates approach. E.g. in Python, I would sort by date in descending order, and then drop_duplicates on the employee ID column. I'm wondering what the equivalent in SQL is, that isn't the greatest-n-per-group method.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff said if you can share your data table we will be able help you better. But you can try using the `MAX` Keyword. Like

```
Select * from your_table t
Where CheckinDate = (select MAX(CheckinDate) from your_table where employeeId = t.employeeId)
```